# How can we send crash errors to own server in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm using Firebase Crashlytics to log crash errors in my react-native app, I want all those logs errors in Crashlytics into my own server. Is there is any way in react-native to handle this, any help would be appreciated.

```
Environment:

"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.4",
"react-native-firebase": "^4.2.0",
```

Comment: Hi, the best way to accomplish this is using Big Query - Crashlytics integration.

Comment: could you please provide me the example how can i accomplish this

Answer (score 4):

If you want crashes to go to firebase AND your server, simply trigger a cloud function on a crash report on crashlytics - 
[documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/extend-with-cloud-functions)

> You can trigger a function in response to Crashlytics issue events including new issues, regressed issues, and velocity alerts. (...) Each event triger created with IssueBuilder returns an Issue with properties that include the issue's name, ID, relevant app info, and more.

Multiple crash listeners on an app isn't a great idea.